How do we put the value of k in the knnquery in using elastic search client?
Hi I'm trying to implement knn in elasticsearch, using maven java, but k is not being accepted in the querybuilder using elasticsearch client.
Query knnQuery = QueryBuilders.knn(m -> m
.queryVector(textDenseVector)
.field("denseEmbeddings")
.k(5)
);
It's not recognising k. It's saying can't resolve the method k in builder.
expected it to accept k as a parameter.

k in this case is not part of the query, it is part of the search request. You need to use the size parameter of the search request for that.
See the first example and a note underneath it in the knn query documentation
